# How can I replicate R subset mechanism in Excel VBA?

Tags: r, vba, excel

First of all thank you for reading my post.

I would like to ask how can I replicate R subset mechanism in [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba)?

Here is my [r](/questions/tagged/r) function:

```
Subdeck2 = deck2[(deck2[,3]>=10 & deck2[,4]<=30),]
```

The code uses [r](/questions/tagged/r) to create a `data.frame` object called `Subdeck2` which is a subset of a `data.frame` object called `deck2` that contain the rows of `deck2` that have a third column value of more than or equal to ten, and a fourth column value of less than or equal to thirty.

I would like to replicate this in [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba), and a worksheet that is a subset of a the worksheet with the source data. I think the array naming in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) is very helpful to reference the rows and columns.

In [r](/questions/tagged/r), it tends to get confusing when I have to do this repeatedly, because I have to remember the row and column numbers that I have already input.

I only need to do this one particular thing in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel). I already bought a book about [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) programming but it's like 1000 pages long and I cant seem to find the word subset in there.

Any suggestions on how to do this or where i can learn to do this will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, generally in R you do not have to rely on row or column numbers to do things like this. For example, this code can easily be written with column names like `deck2[deck2$c >= 10 & deck2$d <= 30, ]` or as `subset(deck2, c >= 10 & d <= 30)` if the 3rd and 4th columns are named `c` and `d`.

Comment: wow yeah you're right, thanks for letting me know. but i still have to use the row and column number though. Because he real function that i realy going to use is that i will use a specific value in a dataframe

Comment: wow yeah you're right, thanks for letting me know. but i still have to use the row and column number though. Because the real function that i really going to use  will use a specific value in a data frame as the conditional value. because i need to do this like more than 200 times. So i need to input the conditional value first in an array to so that i do not need to input the conditional value every time. The real function will be like deck2[deck2$c >= Quartile$A[1,3] & deck2$d <=  Quartile$B[1,3], ] and so on. Anyway thanks for the input i appreciated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example - nowhere near as concise as your [r](/questions/tagged/r) function though.

The method is commented - but basically, it iterates the rows of the source range and checks each row for the criteria. Then it selects the output range and resizes it to the size of the filtered data before output.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterLikeRSubset()

    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim rngFilter As Range
    Dim rngOutput As Range

    'get data
    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D5")

    'iterate rows in data
    For Each rngRow In rngData.Rows
        'test row criteria
        If rngRow.Cells(1, 3) >= 10 And rngRow.Cells(1, 4) <= 30 Then
            'success
            If rngFilter Is Nothing Then
                Set rngFilter = rngRow
            Else
                Set rngFilter = Union(rngFilter, rngRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next rngRow

    'set range for output
    Set rngOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10")
    Set rngOutput = rngOutput.Resize(rngFilter.Rows.Count, rngFilter.Columns.Count)

    'output
    rngOutput.Value = rngFilter.Value

End Sub
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Well i think this will be what i need, i'm going to try this right away. Thanks for your input i really appreciate it. Anyway do you know any particular good book that i can read to learn more about VBA? not the ones that have to many pages though, i prefer 400 to 500 pages tops. One last thing, how do you give thanks in this forum? i'm kinda new to this he.

Comment: You are welcome. You can use the upvote button next to the answer and if the code works for you, you can use the tick button underneath the voting button to indicate that the answer solved your question.

Comment: Yeah this code is really close to what i have in mind, but is there anyway that we can refer the conditional value to a Union of an named array in excel? for example in your code is like `If rngRow.Cells(1, 3) >= "Row3_ Column2_" And rngRow.Cells(1, 4) <= "thirty" Then` ?

Comment: You can refer to values in other ranges in an `If` statement e.g. `If rngRow.Cells(1, 3) >= ws.Cells(x, y).Value And ..`